# Confused about bash conditionals

Tags: bash, if-statement, subprocess

I am confused:

```
echo "i-am-sure-this-is-here" > /tmp/myfile
if [[ $(grep -q sure /tmp/myfile) ]] ; then echo "Found!" ; else echo "wtf! not found" ; fi
```

Which gives:

```
wtf! not found
```

So I try something even simpler:

```
if [[ true ]] ; then echo "true -> expected" ; else echo "true -> unexpected" ; fi
if [[ false ]] ; then echo "false -> unexpected" ; else echo "false -> expected" ; fi
```

Which gives me something unexpected:

```
true -> expected
false -> unexpected
```

I am clearly not understanding this. Some questions:

1. Why is `false` true?
2. Is the conditional evaluating the exit code of the command at all? I expected `0` exit code to mean `true` (the return code if the `true` command), and any non `0` exit code to mean `false` (the `false` command returns `1`)

How to evaluate exit codes of commands in an `if-else-fi` construct in `bash` without having to revert to explicitly comparing the exit code (`$?`) to an expected value, which is ugly and not very readable?

I know this would work:

```
grep -q sure /tmp/myfile
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then echo "Found!" ; else echo "wtf! not found" ; fi
```

But this is longer (2 lines instead of 1), and uglier.

Comment: `[[ <something> ]]` is true if `<something>` is anything but an empty string. `grep -q` doesn’t print anything, so `[[ $(grep -q …) ]]` will always be false. `[[ false ]]` is true because the word `false`, which doesn’t ‘mean’ anything to Bash, is not an empty string. To use `grep` as a condition just use `if grep -q …; then …`.

Comment: _But this is longer (2 lines instead of 1), and uglier_ : Longer and uglier: Yes. As for the number of lines, this depends on you. You can write the whole bash script into one single line, if you prefer. Actually, I would also the `if` statement spread over 6 lines for better readability, instead of squeezing it into one line, but this is a matter of taste.

Comment: You should use the base `test` or `[` built-ins.

Comment: See also [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` tests the status code of its "argument". Therefore

```
if grep -q sure /tmp/myfile
then
  echo found
fi
```

would do the job.

Comment: so `if [[` has as argument `[[`?

Comment: Like `grep`, `[[ ... ]]` is also  a command on it's own, as you can see when you do a (for instance) `[[ abc == *c ]] && echo true`. `[[ ... ]]` sets the exit code to 0 if the condition is fulfilled, and to 1 if it is not.

Comment: @DingDong Kindly have a look at how the [bash conditional expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) work.

Comment: Being a bit pedantic here, but the command is `[[`. The `]]` is just an argument to that command.

Comment: @sjsam I am not confused about conditional expressions, but about how if evaluates the result of those expressions.

Comment: The condition of an `if` statement is the arbitrary command list between `if` and `then` (where a command list is any number of commands joined by `&&`, `||`, `&`, `;` or a newline). The exit status of that list determines which branch, if any, to execute next. The most *common* command lists used with `if` are a simple `test/[` command or the compound command `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: @DingDong `]` is an argument to `[`; `]]` is *not* an argument to `[[`, but rather `[[` and `]]` together define the compound command. (As a compound command, it is parsed and evaluated differently from a simple command; it's how parameter expansion avoids being subject to word-splitting, for example.)

Comment: @chepner Got it! https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html. Bash syntax is convoluted!

Answer (score 1):

Please read about `[[` compound command. Grep with option -q output nothing:

```
$ grep --help
  ...
  -q, --quiet, --silent     suppress all normal output
  ...
```

That is why the first check is failing.
The second check is true for both the tries because this is how `[[ ]]` works true|false doesn't matter you can write down whatever you want here it always be true. Only the empty string will fail.

```
$ [[ yes ]] && echo ok || echo fail
ok

$ [[ no ]] && echo ok || echo fail
ok

$ [[ fail ]] && echo ok || echo fail
ok

$ [[ '' ]] && echo ok || echo fail
fail
```

But you don't actually need to use `test` or `[[]]|[]` to check grep. Use its exit codes:

```
grep -q sure /tmp/myfile && echo ok || echo fail
ok
```

To prevent what Chepner said in comments, this construction can be used:

```
a && (b; exit 0) || c
```

Comment: Your last code is problematic: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015

Comment: `a && b || c` is not equivalent to `if a; then b; else c; fi`. `a && b || c` will execute `c` if `b` is executed and fails.